# How does ListNode.java?

Tags: java, list

```
 package DataStructures;

// Basic node stored in a linked list
// Note that this class is not accessible outside
// of package DataStructures

class ListNode
{
        // Constructors
    ListNode( Object theElement )
    {
        this( theElement, null );
    }

    ListNode( Object theElement, ListNode n )
    {
        element = theElement;
        next    = n;
    }

        // Friendly data; accessible by other package routines
    Object   element;
    ListNode next;
}
```

I have researched on many websites about it but I am still confused on how does it work. I know it is a reference to the next object within the class it is implemented but how does it make that reference? I would like some detailed explanation on this. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The next node reference is given as a constructor argument, called `n`.

```
ListNode( Object theElement, ListNode n )
{
    element = theElement;
    next    = n;   //here it is assigned to the variable next
}
```